# Unable to transform image array 3d to 2d

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 28x28 image that transformed into array with "numpy.array()". But I use "reshape()" or "transpose()" in various ways to leave it in 2d, without success, only unduly distorting the image. Here some try's:

```
#get data from csv
my_data = genfromtxt('train-labels.csv', delimiter=',',dtype=None,names=True)
imgs = my_data['images']
#try's to transform in a 2d array
numpy.array(cv2.imread(imgs[0])).reshape(28,-1)
numpy.array(cv2.imread(imgs[0])).reshape(-1,28)
numpy.array(cv2.imread(imgs[0])).transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,28)
numpy.array(cv2.imread(imgs[0])).transpose(2,0,1).reshape(28,-1)
```

Comment: What's shape of the 3d array? (28,28,3)?  If so do you understand what that size 3 dimension means? What do you expect different in a (28,28) array?

Comment: it is simply an image of MNIST, which I needed to turn it into an array so I could use it with Sklearn. He himself tells me that it have 3 dimensions, and is neccessary an of two

Comment: Without understanding the nature of the 3d array we can't help you.

Comment: Can you give us the result of `numpy.shape(cv2.imread(imgs[0]))`? To echo @hpaulj 's point, a 1D array has shape: `(N1)`. A 2D array has shape `(N1,N2)`. A 3D array has shape `(N1,N2,N3)`. If `N3 == 1` you effectively have a 2D array.

Answer (score 2):

If you read your image as `img = cv2.imread(my_image, 0)`, it will be read as greyscale, and only be two dimensional.